# CSS On Focus First Child Change Color Of Second Child?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

This is My Html Code.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" name="s" placeholder="Search">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

Now This is My CSS.

```
input[type='text']:focus{
    color:#CD4C37;
}
```

I want to change color of only glyphicon not input text.

How can i change color of icon on focus textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input[type='text']:focus + span.glyphicon-ok {
    color:#CD4C37;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is working for me again thank you dear.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution would look something like this:

```css
.form-group > :first-child:focus + span.glyphicon-ok {
  color:#CD4C37;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" name="s" placeholder="Search">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback">Input is focused</span>
</div>
```

That way it can work for other elements such as `<button />`

```css
.form-group > :first-child:focus + span.glyphicon-ok {
  color:#CD4C37;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <button>I'm a button</button>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback">Input is focused</span>
</div>
```

or even `<p />` (Note: you'll need to provide `tabindex=-1`, more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)).

```css
.form-group > :first-child:focus + span.glyphicon-ok {
  color:#CD4C37;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <p tabindex="-1">I'm a paragraph</p>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback">Input is focused</span>
</div>
```